# How to iterate through an XDocument's Nodes

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, sorting

I am trying to iterate through my xml document's nodes to get the value for `<username>Ed</username>` in each node. I am using Linq to sort the XDocument first, then attempting to loop through the nodes. I can't seem to find the correct foreach loop to achieve this. Any help is appreciated.

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("files\\config.xml");
var newDoc = new XDocument(new XElement("Config",
            from p in doc.Element("Config").Elements("Profile")
            orderby int.Parse(p.Element("order").Value)
            select p));


foreach (XElement xe in newDoc.Nodes())
{
    MessageBox.Show(xe.Element("username").Value);
}

// XML document
<Config>
<Profile>
    <id>Scope</id>
    <username>Scope 1</username>
    <password>...</password>
    <cdkey>0000</cdkey>
    <expkey></expkey>
    <cdkeyowner>Scope</cdkeyowner>
    <client>W2BN</client>
    <server>[IP]</server>
    <homechannel>Lobby</homechannel>
    <load>1</load>
    <order>2</order>
</Profile>
<Profile>
    <id>Scope 2</id>
    <username>Scope 2</username>
    <password>...</password>
    <cdkey>0000</cdkey>
    <expkey></expkey>
    <cdkeyowner>Scope</cdkeyowner>
    <client>W2BN</client>
    <server>[IP]</server>
    <homechannel>Lobby</homechannel>
    <load>1</load>
    <order>1</order>
</Profile>
</Config>
```

Comment: Can you post your (abridged) schema, or an (abridged) example file?

Comment: sure,
`code`<Config>
   <Profile>
      <username>Ed</username>
   </Profile>
   <Profile>
      <username>Ed 2</username>
</Config>`code`

Comment: You should be able to put a breakpoint here, run in debug mode, and then inspect the `newDoc` object to determine the correct XML properties to query.

Comment: add the schema to your question instead of a comment, it will be easier to reference

Comment: apologies, I have added it to the question.

Comment: What happens (incorrect etc) with the code you have posted?

Comment: It just simply won't iterate through the nodes. It will fire the foreach one time, and I can't seem to grab any relevant data from the loop.

Comment: Your comment "// Xml Schema" is wrong!  It should be "// Xml Document

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try this. Not sure why you need the second doc.

```
foreach (XElement xe in doc.Descendants("Profile"))
{
    MessageBox.Show(xe.Element("username").Value);
}
```

Comment: the 2nd doc is to sort the first one by `code`<order> in my schema I just didn't include it. This works, but is there a way to loop each node and get the value for all elements in the node? (My schema is shortened, each node holds about 10 elements I need to access).

Comment: post the full schema, or as much is relevant. otherwise, it's hard to guess at what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: posted the full schema. Basically I need to loop through each `code`<Profile> node and get the value for each element inside it.

Comment: Got it to work by changing .Descendants("username") to .Descendants("Profile"). Not sure why I didn't see that before. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Any help with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49014192/how-to-save-sharepoint-feed-xml-node-into-a-variable will be greatly apprecaited.

Answer (score 6):

Its easier to use a XPathDocument and a XPath expression.

```
var doc = new XPathDocument("files\\config.xml")
foreach (var username in doc.CreateNavigator().Select("//username")
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for inner node, i.e. recursive like, you can check for the element has element.
For example assum you reading your xml from database

```
string xmlRoot = "select XmlItem from db";
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlRoot);
List<XElement> xElementList = doc.Descendants().ToList();
foreach(XElement element in xElementList )
{
  // read the element and do with your node
  if(element.HasElements)
    {
      // here you can reach nested node
    }

}
```