# Getting Child nodes of an xDocument element while itereating through the Xdocument

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

Sorry if my question was unclear. I got a bunch of elements and the attributes for each one of them from the xDocument. Now i want in every iteration to get more decedents of every node and iterate through them and get all of their attributes.

structure:

```
<Jobs>
     <Job attr1=val1 attr2=val2 attr3=val3>
          <InnerNode1 InnerAttr1=val6 InnerAttr2=7>
                     <InnerNodeChild1>
                        .........
                     </InnerNodeChild1>
                     <InnerNodeChild2>
                        ............
                     </InnerNodeChild2>
                     <InnerNodeChild3>
                        .......
                     </InnerNodeChild3>
          </InnerNode1>
          <InnerNode2 InnerAttr1=val6 InnerAttr2=7>
                     <InnerNodeChild1>
                        .........
                     </InnerNodeChild1>
                     <InnerNodeChild2>
                        ............
                     </InnerNodeChild2>
                     <InnerNodeChild3>
                        .......
                     </InnerNodeChild3>
          </InnerNode2>
          <InnerNode3 InnerAttr1=val6 InnerAttr2=7>
                     <InnerNodeChild1>
                        .........
                     </InnerNodeChild1>
                     <InnerNodeChild2>
                        ............
                     </InnerNodeChild2>
                     <InnerNodeChild3>
                        .......
                     </InnerNodeChild3>
          </InnerNode3>
     </job>
     <Job attr1=val4 attr2=val5>
          <InnerNode1 InnerAttr1=val6 InnerAttr2=7>
                     <InnerNodeChild1>
                        .........
                     </InnerNodeChild1>
                     <InnerNodeChild2>
                        ............
                     </InnerNodeChild2>
                     <InnerNodeChild3>
                        .......
                     </InnerNodeChild3>
          </InnerNode1>
          <InnerNode2 InnerAttr1=val6 InnerAttr2=7>
                     <InnerNodeChild1>
                        .........
                     </InnerNodeChild1>
                     <InnerNodeChild2>
                        ............
                     </InnerNodeChild2>
                     <InnerNodeChild3>
                        .......
                     </InnerNodeChild3>
          </InnerNode2>
          <InnerNode3 InnerAttr1=val6 InnerAttr2=7>
                     <InnerNodeChild1>
                        .........
                     </InnerNodeChild1>
                     <InnerNodeChild2>
                        ............
                     </InnerNodeChild2>
                     <InnerNodeChild3>
                        .......
                     </InnerNodeChild3>
          </InnerNode3>
     </Job>
     .....
     .....
     .....
     <OtherNodeInSameLevelAsJob>
     </OtherNodeInSameLevelAsJob>
</Jobs>
```

OK, For every **Job Node** there will be just one **InnerNode1** and it has attributes and inner nodes of it self. If I want to get all the attributes and the InnerNodeChilds from every InnerNode1 but while running thru the jobs, like in the next example, What do i need to do?

```
  XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(xDr);
            var Jobs = from Job in xDoc.Descendants("Job")
                       select new {  
                            JobID = Job.Attribute("JobID").Value,
                            JobName = Job.Attribute("JobName").Value,
                            ........
                            ........
                            ........
                        };
```

and then:

```
 foreach(var Job in Jobs){
        string JobId = Job.JobID;
        string JobName = job.JobName;
        .........
        .........
        .........
 }
```

Thank you,
Erez

Comment: Just to be sure. You want a `Jobs` list with only the attributes, InnerNode1 and InnerNode1 children ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Getting every `InnerNode1` is very simple, you just call `.Descendants("InnerNode1")` and you'll have a list of every one of them.  Here's an example that might work for you.  I call parent on the node to get its job name and id.

```
var innerchilds = xDoc.Descendants("InnerNode1").Select(x => new {
    JobID = x.Parent.Attribute("JobID").Value,
    JobName = x.Parent.Attribute("JobName").Value,
    ...
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you meaning select inside a select?

```
var Jobs = from Job in xDoc.Descendants("Job")
                   select new {  
                        JobID = Job.Attribute("JobID").Value,
                        JobName = Job.Attribute("JobName").Value,
                        InnerNode = from inner in Job.Elements("InnerNode")
                            select new
                            {
                               Name = inner.Attribute("Name")
                            }
                        ........
                        ........
                        ........
                    };
```

Comment: Hey, Is was great, thank you, but i'm still having a problem with it.... In your answer you return an xelement named inner and for every inner got it's attributes. I need to get the Inner child of every inner and to the its attributes...I know it should straight forward, just do another select, but the innet child select return empty or null string and i am getting an exception all time when trying to use it.... as i showed before, the innerNodes and the innerChilds are not always in a same number as there siblings and even empty sometimes. and thought about this? 10x :-)

Comment: I am glad it helped! Maybe look at this also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989686/how-to-iterate-through-an-xdocuments-nodes

Comment: You can always do an error checking inside the select. For example replace Job.Attribute("JobName") with: Job.Attribute("JobName") == null ? string.Empty : Job.Attribute("JobName").Value