# How to show specific information on xml

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have a c# console application where I update, add and delete information from an xml which works so far. But when i show the xml in my console with WriteLine it shows like this:

```
<ArrayOfKunde xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Kunde id="1">
    <firstName>Hasan 2</firstName>
    <lastName>sad</lastName>
    <adress>sdfd</adress>
    <birthday>vcxbgf</birthday>
    <bankDetails>bcgh</bankDetails>
  </Kunde>
  <Kunde id="2">
    <firstName>ghf</firstName>
    <lastName>nbv</lastName>
    <adress>bjk</adress>
    <birthday>hjvn</birthday>
    <bankDetails>jhgj</bankDetails>
  </Kunde>
  <Kunde id="3">
    <firstName>mbn,</firstName>
    <lastName>hgj</lastName>
    <adress>ghj</adress>
    <birthday>ghjg</birthday>
    <bankDetails>hghj</bankDetails>
  </Kunde>
</ArrayOfKunde>
```

it is probably due to my code to print it:

```
string filepath = "customerdatabase2.xml";
            var xDoc = XDocument.Load(filepath);
            Console.WriteLine(xDoc);
```

I wanted to ask if there is any way for me to filter what is shown? For example I do not want to show:

```
<ArrayOfKunde xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

Comment: "it shows like this". You haven't really explained how it is supposed to show. You just want to eliminate the root element?

Comment: You need to [iterate over the elements of xDoc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4989769/3150445) and selectively write only those nodes that are children of ArrayOfKunde.  There's probably an XPath expression you can use, but I've been out of that domain for too long to recall the details. Someone will chime in here, I am sure.

Comment: List<Kunde> Kundes = doc.Descendents("Kunde").ToList();  foreach(Kunde kunde in Kundes){ Console.Writeline(kunde.ToString()); }

Answer (score 0):

Use: [XDocument.Descendants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.descendants?view=net-5.0#System_Xml_Linq_XContainer_Descendants)

So your code can be:

```
string filepath = "customerdatabase2.xml";
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(filepath);       

foreach (var node in xDoc.Descendants().Skip(1))
    Console.WriteLine(node);
```

But this is very much tied to your Xml structure. Note that I am skipping 1st descendant because that will be the Top level ArrayOfKunde node.